# jquery set element hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, static, hover

I have a page with 6 menu buttons. Each button has he's own background for hover event (CSS). Everything works fine, but now I want to make that when I'm selecting a page, I want to make that background static. Is it possible to make it with javascript? This would help the visitor to know what type of buttons he was selected.

If you don't get what I mean, I'll wrote a small code in jquery (is this just an example):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#button-index1").makeItStaticBackground();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add a class (Ex menu-element) to element you want apply css hover effect and remove this class when the element is active.

CSS:

```
.menu-element:hover{
...
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#button-index1").removeClass('menu-element');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this by adding a `active` class on the server, or via JavaScript. Via JavaScript you can use some `location.href` === `a.href` magic. And in CSS it's simple:

```
.menu a:hover,
.menu a.active {
    // definitions..
}
```

Comment: .menu a.active is more like it.